# Clear find history in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm really sorry if this question has been asked and it is pretty pedantic but is there a way to clear the find and replace history in visual studio 2008?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know you could clear it by deleting the `FindX` key in the register at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Find` (*Restart of Visual Studio needed*).

Comment: It is still applicable on VS2013 as well, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Find`

Answer (score 2):

Or just in case you are using The C# Express Edition, you could clear them by deleting the `FindX` (`Find0`, `Find1`, `Find2`, and so on) key(s) under the folder: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VCSExpress\9.0\Find`

Answer (score 1):

- Start > Run > Regedit
- Browse to: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Version No\Find`
- Delete the find and replace keywords
- Restart Visual Studio

Its a bit of a hack but its tried and tested and I dont believe there are alternatives.

Also should mention the entries to delete look like this:

- Find
- Find0
- Find1
- Find2

etc...